# php plus X Days but exclude Sundays (strtotime("$newDate +2 Weekdays"));)

Tags: php, html

Using the following code I am able to give an estimated 3-5 working day delivery date on my site.

```
<?php
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$numDays=3;
$holidays = 'https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays/england-and-wales.ics';

    if (!is_array($holidays)) {
        $ch = curl_init($holidays);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        $ics = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $ics = explode("\n",$ics);
        $ics = preg_grep('/^DTSTART;/',$ics);
        $holidays = preg_replace('/^DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).*/s','$1-$2-$3',$ics);
    }

    $addDay = 0;
    while ($numDays--) {
        while (true) {
            $addDay++;
            $newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$date +$addDay Days"));
            $EarliestArrival = date('D jS', strtotime("$newDate +1 Days")); 
            $LatestArrival = date('D jS M', strtotime("$newDate +2 Days"));             
            $newDayOfWeek = date('w', strtotime($newDate));
            $newDayOfWeekText = date('D', strtotime($newDate));
            $newDateUKFormat = date('jS M', strtotime("$date +$addDay Days"));
            if ( $newDayOfWeek>0 && $newDayOfWeek<6 && !in_array($newDate,$holidays)) break;
        }
    }
?>
<div class="3_5daydispatch">Order today for dispatch: <?php echo $newDayOfWeekText; ?> <?php echo $newDateUKFormat; ?><br>Receive between: <?php echo $EarliestArrival; ?> & <?php echo $LatestArrival; ?></div>
```

The issue I am having is that the estimated delivery dates because of the way the code is written to just add on x days currently includes Sundays which it should not as Sunday is not a delivery day for us.

Is there a way to +X Days but exclude Sundays so that is can work with my current code?

I've not tried much as I'm a little clueless as to where to start with this one. I have searched a few similar topics but the solutions don't seem to fit my code flow? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newDate +1 Weekday
```

Seems to do the trick today but tomorrow will show Sunday again for the earliest arrival so this is not the ideal solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this helper function

```
function isWeekend($date) {
    return (date('N', strtotime($date)) >= 6);
}
```

check every day and if is weekend countdown